# Строки в С/С++, удаление элементов

Tags: c++, c, массивы, строки

Задача:
Есть массив char text[20][81], в нем записаны строки, необходимо найти и удалить содержимое правильно расставленных скобок, включая сами скобки.
Сложность заключается в том, каким образом мне нужно определить пару для скобки среди других пар? При том, что скобки могут иметь пару на другой строке.

```
int index = 0, j = 0;//переменные для циклов
int open = 0, close = 0;//подсчет скобок
int arrayL[80] = {};//массив индексов левых скобок
int arrayR[80] = {};//массив индексов правых скобок
int l=0, r=0; // счетчик индексов для массива
while (index < strCount)
{
    while (text[index][j] != NULL)
    {
        switch (text[index][j])
        {
        case '(': 
        {
            open++;
            arrayL[l] = j;
            l++;
        }
        case ')':
        {
            close++;
            arrayR[r] = j;
            r++;
        }

        }
        j++;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Моя попытка создать массив из левых и правых скобок, но в случае если скобки будут на разных строках придётся прикручивать костыль в виде подсчета элементов между ними(планировалось просто отнять от большего меньшее в стандартном случае)

Comment: Координаты скобок x,y f(x,y)=x+y*80 далее по f(x,y) ищем нужные пары как в строке. После удаляем ненужное одним из 2 вариантов. Если y1==y2 то сдвигаем на разницу иксов. Если y1<y2 то пишем в 1 строке 0 в последующих 0 в 0 элемент и в строке y==y2 сдвигаем на x. На с++ сделать это проще ведь есть string.

Comment: В такой схеме не вижу подсчёта символов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i, j, n, k=0;//переменные для цикла
int lenght;//длина строки
int indL[2] = {}, indR[2] = {};//левая и правая скобка соотв.
int flag = 0;//показатель была ли найдена открывающая скобка, 1 - найденна левая скобка
//[0] - координата по У; [1] - координата по Х
//Поиск последней закрывающей скобки
for(i = lineIndex; i < strCount; i++)
{
    lenght = strlen(text[i]);
    for (j = characterIndex; j <= lenght; j++)
    {
        if (text[i][j] == ')')
        {
            indR[0] = i; 
            indR[1] = j;
            for (n = i; n > -1; n--)
            {
                while (k < 81 && k != NULL && k < j)
                {
                    if ('(' == text[i][j])
                    {
                        indL[0] = i;
                        indL[1] = j;
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                if (flag) n = -1;//ОСТАНОВОЧКА
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                brackets[0] = indL[0];
                brackets[1] = indL[1];
                brackets[2] = indR[1];
                brackets[3] = indR[0];
                j = 81;//АСТАНОВОЧКА
                i = strCount;//ТОЖЕ АСТАНОВОЧКА
            }
        }
    }
}
if (flag != 2)
{
    brackets[0] = -1;
    brackets[1] = -1;
    brackets[2] = -1;
    brackets[3] = -1;
}
```

Я решил эту задачу путем поиска закрывающей скобки, т.к. удобнее всего производить поиск парной(просто найти ближайшую). Там если мы нашли закр. скобку, то производится поиск в обратном порядке, пока не найдем открывающую, если не нашли, то ищем другую закрывающую.
Мне показался этот способ самым наглядным. Принимаю критику что можно сделать по другому)

Answer (score 1):

Задача поиска парных скобок стара, как мир :-) И решение её известно давным-давно.

1. Заводим логическую переменную - флажок, сигнализирующий о том, что мы находимся внутри скобок. Вроде *int inside = 0;*
2. Просматриваем весь список строк, как единый буфер (автоматически переходя со строки на строку) и выбираем из него по одному символу.
3. Если *inside == 0* и очередной символ '(' - взводим флаг. Символ НЕ копируем.
4. Если *inside != 0* и очередной символ ')' - сбрасываем флаг. Символ НЕ копируем.
5. Если *inside == 0* просто копируем символ.

Если при достижении конца буфера выяснилось, что *inside != 0*, то это означает, что нарушен синтаксис расстановки скобок.

Разумеется, это очень черновой вариант. Но, я думаю, идея понятна.